# How to set the UILabel's UIColor from a Plist

Tags: objective-c, plist, uilabel, uicolor

the question is in the title, How to set the UILabel's UIColor from a Plist ?

i tried this :

```
UIColor *colorLabel;
```

i add a NSString row in my Plist, and wrote redColor as a value but doesnt work...

How can i handle it ?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would personally store the RGBA values instead of a string and then you can just use

```
 + (UIColor *)colorWithRed:(CGFloat)red green:(CGFloat)green blue:(CGFloat)blue alpha:(CGFloat)alpha
```

---

**Do not do the below**

Just as an interesting side note the most inflexible way would be to use the `UIColor` convenience methods like this

```
[UIColor performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"redColor")]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need convert from string to an UIColor. You put colors into your plist by hex-colors (for red - ff0000) and then use something like following function for get UIColor.

```
+ (UIColor *) colorWithHexString: (NSString *) stringToConvert
{
    NSString *cString = [[stringToConvert stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] uppercaseString];
    // String should be 6 or 8 characters
    if ([cString length] < 6) return [UIColor blackColor];
    // strip 0X if it appears
    if ([cString hasPrefix:@"0X"]) cString = [cString substringFromIndex:2];
    if ([cString length] != 6) return [UIColor blackColor];
    // Separate into r, g, b substrings
    NSRange range;
    range.location = 0;
    range.length = 2;
    NSString *rString = [cString substringWithRange:range];
    range.location = 2;
    NSString *gString = [cString substringWithRange:range];
    range.location = 4;
    NSString *bString = [cString substringWithRange:range];
    // Scan values
    unsigned int r, g, b;
    [[NSScanner scannerWithString:rString] scanHexInt:&r];
    [[NSScanner scannerWithString:gString] scanHexInt:&g];
    [[NSScanner scannerWithString:bString] scanHexInt:&b];
    
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:((float) r / 255.0f)
                        green:((float) g / 255.0f)
                            blue:((float) b / 255.0f)
                        alpha:1.0f];
}
```

Comment: Or you could just save the RGBA values and not have to mess around with the conversion...

Answer (score 0):

To preserve human readability, I did a category for this:

```
@implementation UIColor (EPPZRepresenter)


NSString *NSStringFromUIColor(UIColor *color)
{
    const CGFloat *components = CGColorGetComponents(color.CGColor);
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"[%f, %f, %f, %f]",
            components[0],
            components[1],
            components[2],
            components[3]];
}

UIColor *UIColorFromNSString(NSString *string)
{
    NSString *componentsString = [[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[" withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"]" withString:@""];
    NSArray *components = [componentsString componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:[(NSString*)components[0] floatValue]
                           green:[(NSString*)components[1] floatValue]
                            blue:[(NSString*)components[2] floatValue]
                           alpha:[(NSString*)components[3] floatValue]];
}


@end
```

The same formatting that is used by NSStringFromCGAffineTransform. This is actually a part of a bigger scale plist object representer in [eppz!kit at GitHub](https://github.com/eppz/eppz-kit).